# Is there a way to get the sql statement about the creation of the row type?

Tags: informix, rowtype, user-defined-data-types

Example:

```
create row type custom_type string(street VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR(20); getDDl(custom_type);
```

I think the server should store information about row type fields. However, I did not find information about fields or ddl type in the system tables. The documentation says - [Field Definition clause defines an ordered list of the data types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statements-create-row-type-statement#ids_sqs_0475:%7E:text=Field%20Definition%20clause%20defines%20an%20ordered%20list%20of%20the%20data%20types). But at the moment I couldn't find where this list is stored. Does Informix store information about row type fields anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax given in the example appears to be incorrect, or at least is not recognized by an Informix server. If it is rewritten as:

```
CREATE ROW TYPE custom_type(street VARCHAR(20), city VARCHAR(20));
```

then it will be accepted as valid by Informix.

The command `dbschema -d <database> -u all` may be used to obtain the definition of the row type. Unlike other options of the `dbschema` command, only the keyword `all` may be used to obtain information about all user-defined data types. It is not possible to use the name of a specific row type.

Internally, the information relating to row types is stored in the [SYSXTDTYPES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-sysxtdtypes) and [SYSATTRTYPES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-sysattrtypes) system catalog tables. An example query to retrieve this information:

```
SELECT x.name, a.* FROM sysattrtypes a, sysxtdtypes x
WHERE a.extended_id = x.extended_id AND x.name = "custom_type";
```

This provides the output:

```
name         custom_type
extended_id  2049
seqno        1
levelno      0
parent_no    0
fieldname
fieldno      0
type         4118
length       42
xtd_type_id  0

name         custom_type
extended_id  2049
seqno        2
levelno      1
parent_no    1
fieldname    street
fieldno      1
type         13
length       20
xtd_type_id  0

name         custom_type
extended_id  2049
seqno        3
levelno      1
parent_no    1
fieldname    city
fieldno      2
type         13
length       20
xtd_type_id  0
```

Refer to the documentation for the SYSATTRYPES system catalog for details of how to interpret the stored information.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, thank you. I did not notice this system table in the documentation. Thank you very much